# How do I marshal a C# struct ref without IntPtr?

Tags: c#, clr

I have a couple C structures that looks something like:

```
struct Bar
{
    int x;
};

struct Foo
{
    Bar* bar;
};
```

I would like to create C# structures that looks like this:

```
struct Bar
{
    Int32 x;
}

struct Foo
{
    Bar? bar;
}
```

So I can marshal Foo between C/C# and in C# access x like `foo.bar.x`.

It has been a long time since I have done any interop work, but I am guessing that since `Nullable<T>` is a ValueType this won't do what I want and correctly marshal to a `Bar*`.  I know that I could make Foo look like `struct Foo { IntPtr bar; }` but I would like to avoid having to manually marshal the IntPtr into a Bar later, I would prefer it if the marshaller just did it for me smartly up front.

Is there a way I can annotate `bar` such that it will let me marshal the strongly typed Bar pointer?

**Follow-up**: If there is no way to have C# do the marshalling automatically, what are some patterns and practices that people follow for solving this kind of problem?

Comment: The marshal system will not transform an inline value type into a heap-allocated object with a pointer, you will have to do this transformation yourself.

Comment: Added a follow-up question.

Comment: This is an XY Problem, such an api is just as hard to reliably interop with from a C program.  Fire the C programmer, he doesn't understand memory management.

Comment: It is not an XY problem since I didn't write the underlying C API.  I have a third party API that I have to work with and I cannot change.  I need to come up with the most reasonable way to work with it in C# given the constraint that I am stuck with the C API as it is.